# MySQL SELECT is taking too long to execute

Tags: php, mysql, timeout

I currently have involved 5 tables in this SELECT process. and maybe this query go through 20,000 records or more.

```
        $sql = "SELECT
                    ar_ledger.`company_code` AS ar_ledger_company_code,
                    ar_ledger.`project_code` AS ar_ledger_project_code,
                    ar_ledger.`phase_code` AS ar_ledger_phase_code,
                    ar_ledger.`unit_no` AS ar_ledger_unit_no,
                    ar_ledger.`sales_seq` AS ar_ledger_sales_seq,
                    ar_ledger.`debtor_acc` AS ar_ledger_debtor_acc,                                                
                    pr_tenancy.`name` AS pr_tenancy_name,
                    pr_tenancy.`terminate_date` AS pr_tenancy_terminate_date,
                    pr_tenancy.`status` AS pr_tenancy_status,
                    pr_tenancy_unit.`unit_no` AS pr_tenancy_unit_unit_no,
                    gn_trx_code.`bank_flag` AS bank_flag
               FROM
                    `ar_ledger` ar_ledger
                    INNER JOIN `pr_tenancy` pr_tenancy ON ar_ledger.`debtor_acc` = pr_tenancy.`debtor_acc` AND ar_ledger.`company_code` = pr_tenancy.`company_code` AND ar_ledger.`project_code` = pr_tenancy.`project_code` AND ar_ledger.`phase_code` = pr_tenancy.`phase_code`
                    INNER JOIN `pr_tenancy_unit` pr_tenancy_unit ON ar_ledger.`debtor_acc` = pr_tenancy_unit.`debtor_acc` AND
                        ar_ledger.`company_code` = pr_tenancy_unit.`company_code` AND ar_ledger.`project_code` = pr_tenancy_unit.`project_code` AND ar_ledger.`phase_code` = pr_tenancy_unit.`phase_code`
                    INNER JOIN pd_unit ON (pr_tenancy_unit.`company_code` = pd_unit.`company_code`)
                        AND (pr_tenancy_unit.`project_code` = pd_unit.`project_code`)
                        AND (pr_tenancy_unit.`phase_code` = pd_unit.`phase_code`)
                        AND (pr_tenancy_unit.`unit_no` = pd_unit.`unit_no`)
                    INNER JOIN gn_trx_code ON (ar_ledger.`company_code` = gn_trx_code.`company_code`)
                        AND (ar_ledger.`trx_code` = gn_trx_code.`trx_code`)
               WHERE
                     ar_ledger.`status`='A' AND ar_ledger.`ledger_type` = 'P' AND                          
                     CASE WHEN '$company'<>'' THEN ar_ledger.`company_code`='$company' ELSE ar_ledger.`company_code` IS NOT NULL END AND 
                     CASE WHEN '$project'<>'' THEN ar_ledger.`project_code`='$project' ELSE ar_ledger.`project_code` IS NOT NULL END AND 
                     CASE WHEN '$phase'<>'' THEN ar_ledger.`phase_code`='$phase' ELSE ar_ledger.`phase_code` IS NOT NULL END AND 
                     CASE WHEN '$property'<>'' THEN pd_unit.`property_code`='$property' ELSE pd_unit.`property_code` IS NOT NULL END AND 
                     CASE WHEN '$status'<>'' THEN pr_tenancy_unit.`status`='$status' ELSE pr_tenancy_unit.`status` IS NOT NULL END
               GROUP BY
               ar_ledger.`debtor_acc`
               ORDER BY
               ar_ledger.`debtor_acc`";

        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $total = mysql_num_rows($query);

        $maindata = array();
        $count = 1;
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
            //echo '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Processing '.$count.' rows...");</script>';

            $percent = intval($count/$total * 100)."%";

            // Javascript for updating the progress bar and information
            echo '<script language="javascript">
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="<div style=\"width:'.$percent.';background-color:#ddd;\">&nbsp;</div>";
            document.getElementById("information").innerHTML="'.$percent.' processed.";
            </script>';  

            //terimaan awal
            $ksql1 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='C' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND YEAR(trx_date)=YEAR(DATE_ADD(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'),INTERVAL -1 YEAR))";
            $kamt1 = mysql_result(mysql_query($ksql1), 0);

            $ksql2 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='D' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND YEAR(trx_date)=YEAR(DATE_ADD(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'),INTERVAL -1 YEAR))";
            $kamt2 = mysql_result(mysql_query($ksql2), 0);                



            $dsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger
                        INNER JOIN gn_trx_code ON (ar_ledger.`company_code` = gn_trx_code.`company_code`)
                        AND (ar_ledger.`trx_code` = gn_trx_code.`trx_code`) 
                        WHERE ar_ledger.company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.mode='C' AND ar_ledger.ledger_type='P' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_type='C' AND ar_ledger.analysis_code='-' 
                        AND gn_trx_code.bank_flag='N'
                        AND ar_ledger.debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.status='A' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $kontra_deposit = mysql_result(mysql_query($dsql), 0);


            $msql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='D' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' AND trx_type='D' 
                        AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $tuntutan = mysql_result(mysql_query($msql), 0);


            $jsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        INNER JOIN gn_trx_code ON (ar_ledger.`company_code` = gn_trx_code.`company_code`)
                        AND (ar_ledger.`trx_code` = gn_trx_code.`trx_code`) 
                        WHERE ar_ledger.company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."'
                        AND ar_ledger.phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND gn_trx_code.bank_flag='Y'
                        AND ar_ledger.mode='C' AND ar_ledger.ledger_type='P' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_type='C' AND ar_ledger.analysis_code='-' 
                        AND ar_ledger.debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.status='A' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $bayaran = mysql_result(mysql_query($jsql), 0);


            $rsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='D' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND trx_type='DN' AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $pelarasan_debit = mysql_result(mysql_query($rsql), 0);


            $psql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='C' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND trx_type='CN' AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $pelarasan_kredit = mysql_result(mysql_query($psql), 0);


            $adsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger
                        INNER JOIN gn_trx_code ON (ar_ledger.`company_code` = gn_trx_code.`company_code`)
                        AND (ar_ledger.`trx_code` = gn_trx_code.`trx_code`)  
                        WHERE ar_ledger.company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.mode='D' AND ar_ledger.ledger_type='P' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_type='DA' AND ar_ledger.analysis_code='-' 
                        AND gn_trx_code.bank_flag = 'N'
                        AND ar_ledger.debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.status='A' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $adjustment_debit = mysql_result(mysql_query($adsql), 0);


            $acsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger
                        INNER JOIN gn_trx_code ON (ar_ledger.`company_code` = gn_trx_code.`company_code`)
                        AND (ar_ledger.`trx_code` = gn_trx_code.`trx_code`) 
                        WHERE ar_ledger.company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.mode='C' AND ar_ledger.ledger_type='P' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_type='CA' AND ar_ledger.analysis_code='-' 
                        AND gn_trx_code.bank_flag = 'N' 
                        AND ar_ledger.debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND ar_ledger.status='A' 
                        AND ar_ledger.trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date('$dateForm','%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $adjustment_kredit = mysql_result(mysql_query($acsql), 0);


            $tsql1 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='C' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND trx_type='C' AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date(CONCAT('01-01-',YEAR(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'))),'%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $tamt1 = mysql_result(mysql_query($tsql1), 0);

            $tsql2 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='D' AND ledger_type='P' 
                        AND trx_type='D' AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A' 
                        AND trx_date BETWEEN str_to_date(CONCAT('01-01-',YEAR(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'))),'%d-%m-%Y') AND str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y')";
            $tamt2 = mysql_result(mysql_query($tsql2), 0);
            //$terimaan_thsyr = $tamt1 - $tamt2;

            $bsql = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='D' 
                        AND ledger_type='P'                             
                        AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A'                          
                        AND  YEAR(trx_date)<=YEAR(DATE_ADD(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'),INTERVAL -1 YEAR))";
            $bquery = mysql_query($bsql);
            $debit_amt = mysql_result($bquery, 0);

            $bsql2 = "SELECT COALESCE(SUM(trx_amt),0.00) FROM ar_ledger 
                        WHERE company_code='".$data['ar_ledger_company_code']."' 
                        AND project_code='".$data['ar_ledger_project_code']."' 
                        AND phase_code='".$data['ar_ledger_phase_code']."' 
                        AND mode='C' 
                        AND ledger_type='P'                             
                        AND analysis_code='-' 
                        AND debtor_acc = '".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."' 
                        AND status='A'                          
                        AND  YEAR(trx_date)<=YEAR(DATE_ADD(str_to_date('$dateTo','%d-%m-%Y'),INTERVAL -1 YEAR))";
            $bquery2 = mysql_query($bsql2);
            $credit_amt = mysql_result($bquery2, 0);

            $bal_awal = $debit_amt - $credit_amt;
            if($bal_awal>0){
                $baki_awal = $bal_awal;
                $terimaan_awal = 0;
            }else{
                $baki_awal = 0;
                $terimaan_awal = abs($bal_awal);
            }

            $balance = ($baki_awal<0?0:$baki_awal)-($terimaan_awal<0?0:$terimaan_awal)+($tuntutan<0?0:$tuntutan)-($bayaran<0?0:$bayaran)-($kontra_deposit<0?0:$kontra_deposit)+($pelarasan_debit<0?0:$pelarasan_debit)-($pelarasan_kredit<0?0:$pelarasan_kredit)+($adjustment_debit<0?0:$adjustment_debit)-($adjustment_kredit<0?0:$adjustment_kredit);

            if($balance > 0){
                $tunggakan_eachline = $balance;
                $terimaan_thsyr = 0;
            }else{
                $tunggakan_eachline = 0;
                $terimaan_thsyr = abs($balance);
            }

            if((($data['pr_tenancy_status']=="T") && ($baki_awal>0 || $terimaan_awal>0 || $tunggakan_eachline>0 || $terimaan_thsyr>0))||($data['pr_tenancy_status']!="T")||($data['pr_tenancy_status']=="T" && $data['pr_tenancy_terminate_date']>=ConvertToMySQLDate($dateForm))){
                $subdata = array();
                $subdata['account_name'] = $data['pr_tenancy_name']."-".$data['ar_ledger_debtor_acc']."-".$data['pr_tenancy_unit_unit_no'];
                $subdata['baki_awal'] = $baki_awal;
                $subdata['terimaan_awal'] = $terimaan_awal;
                $subdata['kontra_deposit'] = $kontra_deposit;
                $subdata['tuntutan'] = $tuntutan;
                $subdata['bayaran'] = $bayaran;
                $subdata['pelarasan_debit'] = $pelarasan_debit;
                $subdata['pelarasan_kredit'] = $pelarasan_kredit;
                                $subdata['adjustment_debit'] = $adjustment_debit;
                $subdata['adjustment_kredit'] = $adjustment_kredit;
                $subdata['terimaan_thsyr'] = $terimaan_thsyr;
                $subdata['tunggakan_eachline'] = $tunggakan_eachline;
                $subdata['tenancy_status'] = $data['pr_tenancy_status'];
                $subdata['terminate_date'] = $data['pr_tenancy_terminate_date'];
                $maindata[] = $subdata;
            }
            $count ++;
            // This is for the buffer achieve the minimum size in order to flush data
            echo str_repeat(' ',1024*64);

            // Send output to browser immediately
            flush();

            // Sleep one second so we can see the delay
            sleep(1);     
        }
```

This query doesnt give any response even after waiting for 30 minutes. There is a progress bar which will be updated on every loop, but the thing is, when I run **`mysql> show full processlist`**,when the progress bar are buffering, the mysql status for this query is `sleep`. However, there is mysql activity before the progress bar displays. Is there anything wrong with the codes? Thank you

[image: EXPLAIN Results]

Comment: Try running the queries in MySQL console / through PhpMyAdmin while slowly removing parts of the query to look for bottlenecks.

Comment: add `explain` and see what it tells you

Comment: Perhaps indexing would help. 20,000 records is a fair few.

Comment: Which query is having the problem? The first one? The case statements in where seem outta place to me. I'd put something like that in the select statements. How are you using those values?

Comment: @Dagon i've put the explain result in the question

Comment: @jbrahy the first query is taking a long time already tho

Comment: Can we see the echo too/instead?

Answer (score 0):

**OVER 5 1/2 HOURS IN SLEEP**

"maybe this query go through 20,000 records or more."

How many rows does that first query actually return? (You can test the query from another environment. You can get a count of rows the query by referencing it as an inline view...  `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ( <original query here> ) q`.

If that query is returning 20,000+ rows (as your question seems to indicate), it looks like that **`sleep(1)`** statement at the bottom of the fetch loop is going to be executed 20,000 times. And if I'm doing the math right, that's 20,000+ seconds, which is over 333 minutes, which is over 5 1/2 hours of sleep time.

Comment: Im still testing the row count which is also taking a long time a bit. The SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST are stating 'copying to tmp table'

Comment: it seems that in my localhost db records, only 1520 records exit, but it takes time too. sql SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST showing 'copying to tmp table'